# Using php to write into django ORM

Tags: php, django, orm, data-transfer

I use a php library where something similar does not exist for python / django. So I wrote a php script using the library and now I would like to use the resulting data in Django.

I can think of two approaches to get the php data into Django:

1. I could use php to write into the mysql database that I use for the Django ORM.
2. I could write my php results into a local file and trigger Django by calling a view via http or via a management command to import the data.

Is there a commonly accepted way of doing such things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Django ORM ( means you are using a Django in somewhere in the app), then the approaches you are given is ok and acceptable.
But if all you want is an ORM, then why not try a PHP one like [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent) ?

Betterway for two `tech`s can communicate is using any IPC mechanisms like Process/TCP/Http direct (or RPC).

or

```
$command = "python manage.py storedata" // custom manage command
$output = shell_exec($command); // or $output = `python manage.py storedata`
```

But keeping two codebases, in future will become unmaintainable, so use any PHP native solution.